# list json array within a price range in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting

I  am stuck with a problem. I need to list json array elements with in a range. Don't know how to do........

Controller page

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$cat_id = $_POST['category'];
$post1 = file_get_contents("....?search=".$search."&category=".$cat_id);
$data = CJSON::decode($post1, true);
$products = $data['products'];
$pricerange = $_POST['pricerange'];
$myArray = explode('-',$pricerange);
$a =explode('$',$myArray[0]);
$b =explode('$',$myArray[1]);
```

`$a` is the lower limit and `$b` is the upper limit, `$products` is the json array that has to be listed.

I need to know how to list `$products` based on price range between `$a` and `$b´.
output of $products

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11027
            [title] => SPIDERMAN ENGRAVED LIGHTER
            [barcode] => LEN-0022
            [qty] => 8
            [url] => http://www.ebay.com/itm/-/381279328138?
            [retail_price] => 9.99
            [category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 34
                    [name] => ENGRAVED LIGHTERS
                )

            [bin] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 346
                    [name] => F10
                )

            [images] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [small] => http://www.heygidday.biz/portal//timthumb.php?src=/files/products/dscn124900.jpg&w=30
                            [middle] => http://www.heygidday.biz/portal//timthumb.php?src=/files/products/dscn124900.jpg&w=100
                            [source] => http://www.heygidday.biz/portal/files/products/dscn124900.jpg
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11548
            [title] => SPIDER MAN Black Lighter
            [barcode] => LEN-0067
            [qty] => 6
            [url] => http://www.ebay.com/itm/-/361369988738?
            [retail_price] => 10.99
            [category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 34
                    [name] => ENGRAVED LIGHTERS
                )

            [bin] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 346
                    [name] => F10
                )

            [images] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [small] => http://www.heygidday.biz/portal//timthumb.php?src=/files/products/len-00670.jpg&w=30
                            [middle] => http://www.heygidday.biz/portal//timthumb.php?src=/files/products/len-00670.jpg&w=100
                            [source] => http://www.heygidday.biz/portal/files/products/len-00670.jpg
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

please help me with this.......

Comment: you can change json to array and then sort the array

Comment: how to sort this array within price range

Comment: Did you try it using mysql query? It will be more easy and fast

Comment: i don't have database. data are provided directly as json file.

Comment: did you check the solution?

Comment: s i got the result, thanks for your time and the solution..

Comment: Welcome, Please accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

I have created a little script for you, It should help

```
    function sortbyprice($a, $b) {
        return $a['retail_price'] - $b['retail_price'];
    }
    $result_Array = array(
        array('id'=>'11027','retail_price'=>'9.99'),
        array('id'=>'11548','retail_price'=>'10.99'),
        array('id'=>'11528','retail_price'=>'3.99'),
        array('id'=>'18548','retail_price'=>'55.99')
    );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result_Array);
usort($result_Array, 'sortbyprice');
print_r($result_Array);
```